# Java EE + JKS vs C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, jks

from .NET 3.5 C# web application we want to connect to Java WebService. There are security checks using JKS certificate. How can we use it / send it in web method call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be closed now, we got a p12 file instead.